# How to select all child nodes on selecting parent in kendo TreeList? javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I'm trying to select child nodes on parent node clicked. I couldn't find any example for select api. Should i use checkbox instead?

```
<button id="btn">Highlight third row</button>
<div id="treeList"></div>
<script>
  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    columns: [
      { field: "id" },
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Jane Doe", age: 22, expanded: true },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 24 },
      { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Jenny Doe", age: 3 }
    ],
    selectable: "multiple row"
  });

</script>
```

I am trying to do that if select "1" (top parent), select 2,3 (child nodes). Hope there is native solution for javascript implementation. Thanks in advice!

Comment: Do you want the children selected if the parent is not expanded ?  Do you want the children de-selected if the parent is de-selected ?

Comment: @Richard Yes i need something like that.Also a child has children too. When i select outer child node then i need inner child nodes too. Then on click a button that will return ids (which has no child) to me so i can go on. But i couldn't find any example for this scenario. Hope you help me sir!

Comment: Also i should note that i work 1 to 30k nodes (depends ea acc). I tried treeview but it has troubles with paging and performance while selecting checkboxes and filtering. So i see that kendoTreeList looks much better for my situation but it seems a new feature so i can't find examples about custom problems..

Comment: For demonstration purposes, your dataSource is an array.  What is the actual dataSource ?  The messy part is the unexpanded nodes. You might select all children nodes upon expansion or data bound using criteria 'is direct parent node' selected.  If such criteria is used you need to track 'first expansion' -- why ?  Suppose you selected id 1, then expanded it (which some code auto selects 2&3), then 2&3 are deselected and 1 collapsed and expanded again... should 2&3 become reselected after having been deselected?

Comment: Should also think about what to do for dynamically loaded children. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/treelistdatasource/methods/load

Comment: I don't know that how to select child nodes if i select parent directly. Do you have any show case for this? I think select and expand/collapse different things for my situation. There is already an arrow for expand/collapse case but no way to select childs on select parent node.

Answer (score 0):

The selection state is maintained by TreeList in the data items row rendering`<tr k-state-selected>`, and that state is not reflected in the TreeList `dataSource`.  Also, the data source is the only place the child relationship is discoverable.  So there is a bit of back and forth to deal with selections and children.

Also `TreeList` does not have a `select` event like `TreeView` so out of the box you do not know which nodes were selected or deselected.

The `change` event fires when one action causes one or more rows (like shift-click can do) are caused to be selected or deselected.  Within your `change` handler you can only know the current state of all selected rows using the `select()` method.

Thus, within `change`, you need to track prior selection state and current selection state to find **which** rows changed selection state, which would merit their children to be selected or deselected according to your requirement.

[See this Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/eYIRaFaH/10) for an example.  It's not perfect because in the `change` event you can only determine selected nodes and not know if a 'reselection' occurred (i.e. clicked on a selected row again).  Anyway, the descent down the hierarchy of the TreeList is performed recursively and relies on the `dataSource` data item property `.hasChildren` and dataSource method `.childNodes()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TreeList select (change)</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.219/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <p><a target="_blank" href="https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist">TreeList docs</a></p>
  <div id="treeList"></div>
<script>
  selected_uids = [];              // track selected uids
  autoselecting = false;

  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    columns: [
      { field: "id" },
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { id: 1, parentId: null, name: "Jane Doe", age: 22, expanded: false },
      { id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "John Doe", age: 24 },
      { id: 3, parentId: 1, name: "Jenny Doe", age: 3 },
      { id: 4, parentId: null, name: "Jane Mack", age: 22, expanded: false },
      { id: 5, parentId: 4, name: "John Mack", age: 24 },
      { id: 6, parentId: 4, name: "Jenny Mack", age: 3 }      
    ],
    selectable: "multiple row",
      change: function(e) {
      if (autoselecting) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      }

      debugger;

      autoselecting = true;

      var selected_rows = this.select();
      console.log ('desel',selected_rows, selected_uids);

      // check for new deselections
      for (var index = 0; index < selected_uids.length; index++) {
        var selected_uid = selected_uids[index];
        if (selected_uid) {
            var row = $("tr[data-uid='" + selected_uid + "'].k-state-selected");
          if (row.length == 0) {
            // no such selected row for one that was previously tracked as selected
            deselectChildren(this, selected_uid);
            selected_uids[index] = null; // untrack
          }
        }
      }

      var selected_rows = this.select();
      console.log ('sel',selected_rows,selected_uids);

      // check for new selections
      for (var index = 0; index < selected_rows.length; index++) {        
        var data = this.dataItem(selected_rows[index]);
        console.log('data',data);
        if (jQuery.inArray(data.uid, selected_uids) == -1) { 
          // new selection
          selected_uids.push(data.uid);
          selectChildren(this, data);
        }
      }

      for (var i=0, j=0; i < selected_uids.length; i++) {
        if (selected_uids[i] != null) {
          if (i > j) {
            selected_uids[j] = selected_uids[i];
          }
          j++;
        }
      }

      selected_uids.length = j;

      autoselecting = false;
    },
  });

  function selectChildren(treeList, data) {
    if (!data.hasChildren) return;

    var children = treeList.dataSource.childNodes(data);    

    for (var index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {
      var child = children[index];
      if (jQuery.inArray(child.uid, selected_uids) == -1) {
          selected_uids.push(child.uid);
          treeList.select($("tr[data-uid='" + child.uid + "']"));
        selectChildren(treeList,child);
      }
    }
  }  

  function deselectChildren(treeList, uid) {
    var data = treeList.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    if (!(data && data.hasChildren)) return;

    var children = treeList.dataSource.childNodes(data);

    for (var index = 0; index < children.length; index++) {
      var child = children[index];
            var row = $("tr[data-uid='" + child.uid + "'].k-state-selected");      
      if (row.length == 1) {
          var at = selected_uids.indexOf(child.uid);
        if (at >= 0) selected_uids[at] = null;
        row.removeClass('k-state-selected');
      }
      deselectChildren(treeList,child.uid);
    }
  }

  $("#treeList").data("kendoTreeList").select($("#treeList tbody>tr:nth(0)"));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```